# How to get the indices of the three LARGEst elements from a spread sheet

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-docs

I am trying to extract some data in Google Docs but I don't exactly know how. Here is my data:

[image]

I am counting the appearances of the words in the left in some other table. So the other table contained the word "Drachen" exactly once the word "Pantheon" exactly two times and so on.

Now I want to print the three words which appeared the most often at the bottom of the table. Now you see "Pantheon", "Drachen" and again "Drachen".

My problem: I want it to print "Legion" instead of another "Drachen", or any word which appeared once as well. Right now I can't select the index of a different word which appeared exactly once, because it simply searches for the first entry of the second highest value and returns that (which is always the index of "Drachen").

How do I have to change my code, which is right now:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$25;MATCH(LARGE(B$2:B$25;1);B$2:B$25;0);0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try formula:

`=QUERY({A1:B25},"select Col1 order by Col2 desc limit 3")`

it uses SQL query to get top 3 values from list in A1:A25.